# securityinspector for org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean

Tags: spring-security

Can anybody help me out wheather Spring provide security inspector for org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean (purpose i have RPC/ENCODED secure webService)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Does not support RPC style. Its only support document style.